# Ms teams Bot icon is not displayed (NodeJs) (MsBotFramework V4)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created a bot from MS TEAMS App Studio. I have also uploaded the icons in the manifest file. But When bot is sending any messages the default icon is shown instead of the icon that I have uploaded in manifest file

[image]

Not sure why this is happening ?

Any help would be thankfull

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: **Thank You** for accepting answer, this will help others in the community with similar question. Could you please spare one min to let us know how we did by clicking on **[this feedback link](https://aka.ms/DevSupportFeedback)**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your bot in azure >> go to settings on left hand side  - you will see the first option to upload custom bot icon. This will update your icon.

Comment: This option does not exist when using Azure "App Services". Both icons are set directly in AppStudio, which then generates the App package that is uploaded into the MS-Teams space.

Comment: Check this - Go to "https://dev.botframework.com/" >> your bot >> setting - here you will see option to update your bot image.